# Powershell Delete used Variables

Tags: powershell

I appear to have a problem deleting used variables with are locking files, before reusing the same path/file.

First I am declaring a path for my SQL process to write each line into a database:

```
$Files = get-childitem $Folder -Include *COMMON* -Recurse;
```

Next append the file then move it, but the appending the file name fails:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path $Folder where-object { $_.Name -like "*COMMON*" }| rename-item -newname {$DateTime + $_.Name}
```

Using something line:

```
$Files.delete()
```

Before attempting to access the path gives me

Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."
At line:1 char:1
+ $Files.Delete()

If I check the file, it is locked by Powershell...

Are there any solutions to this? I need to process the files in the folder then rename and move them all in one execution of my script... :(

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm writing files from a folder which match a specific value to my database, then marking these files as processed. I think the solutions provided might fix my problem. I will test tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

$datetime is not defined in the code that you've posted.

If you've defined it elsewhere, using code such as `$datetime = get-date`, then the append operation will fail because $datetime is not a string. By executing `$datetime.gettype()` you would see it is a `System.DateTime` object. In PS two easy ways to convert an object into a string are 1) to interpolate it: `"$datetime$($_.name)"` or 2) use ToString(): `$datetime.tostring() + $_.name`

Comment: Your correct, I am defining the date as `$DateTime = get-date -Format "yyyyMMdd"`. I will give your suggestion a try, this seems to be what I'm looking for :)

Comment: @user3791797 I don't think my suggestion will help in this case. Using the -Format parameter converts the date to a string. However I see that you have `{$DateTime + $_.Name}`. Braces are used to delimit a script block. However the -newname parameter requires a string. Use parenthesis instead of braces. BTW, if you ask questions on SO in the future, I suggest you include more details, like the error message you got on the rename, and how you got $datetime.

Comment: The error that the file is in use, and if I check what process is using the file, it is powershell, but yes you make a valid point I will post the error in future. I will check your solution just now and let you know either way. I will try to reproduce the error first to provide what should have been added to my initial description, should it help someone in future ;)

Comment: The OP says "appending the file name fails" (in addition to the failure deleting the file) so it's not clear which failure you are asking about.